# How do i Use One Single Button for multiple activities, after clicking listview?

Tags: android, image, listview, button, onclicklistener

This is my MainActivity i want to use single button which will need to be used like Multiple Button similar to listview. Please Help me out.
[After Clicking Image This Activity open in this i want to use a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx7Jo.jpg)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<DataItem> lstData;
Button button;
int pos = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lstData = new ArrayList<>();

    lstData.add(new DataItem(R.drawable.image_1, "Katrina kaif", "34", "something"));
    lstData.add(new DataItem(R.drawable.image_2, "Deepika Padukone", "34", "something"));
    lstData.add(new DataItem(R.drawable.image_3, "Disha Patani", "34", "something"));
    lstData.add(new DataItem(R.drawable.image_4, "Tamanna Bhatia", "34", "something"));

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemrow, lstData);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Actress", lstData.get(position).actressName);
            intent.putExtra("Image", lstData.get(position).resIdThumbnail);
            intent.putExtra("Age", lstData.get(position).actressAge);
            intent.putExtra("About", lstData.get(position).actressAbout);
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

In this activity there is button i need that button to trigger another activity.

activity_main2.xml

Please Look at the Image i posted

Main2Activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView nameView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_1);
    TextView ageView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.age_1);
    TextView aboutView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.about_1);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.img_btn);

    textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Actress"));
    nameView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Actress"));
    ageView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Age"));
    aboutView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("About"));
    imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("Image",R.drawable.image_1));
    circleImageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("Image",R.drawable.image_1));
    button.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("Position",R.id.img_btn));
}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your meaning by `single` or `multiple` button. Can you explain more?

Comment: single button. I have two activitys one is MainActivity and another one Main2Activity.i used a listview in that i implemented onitemclick listener from that i sent some data to Main2Activity. finally i have a button in that activity i need to open another activity with that. Sorry for my bad english skills.